# Anchored sprite lags when the underlying sprite moves in Phaser

Tags: phaser-framework

On this link there is an example of a game developed using Phaser
[http://examples.phaser.io](http://examples.phaser.io/_site/view_full.html?d=games&f=tanks.js&t=tanks). 
Your tank is a sprite with a turret sprite anchored on it:

```
//  The base of our tank
tank = game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'tank', 'tank1');
tank.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);

...

//  Finally the turret that we place on-top of the tank body
turret = game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'tank', 'turret');
turret.anchor.setTo(0.3, 0.5);
..
```

Also notice the following in the update function that executes every frame:

```
turret.x = tank.x;
turret.y = tank.y;
```

Notice that when you accelerate, the turret lags a bit and catches up with the underlying tank sprite only when you reach zero velocity. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

a little bit late.. you should consider that your sprite uses physics that renders in various sections. Try to see API DOCs preUpdate, postUpdate, Phaser.World.

So, in your case, if you use for instance ARCADE Physics, you should reload data of your x,y via body which belongs to arcade.physics, not other.

```
tank = game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'tank', 'tank1');
tank.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
game.physics.enable(tank, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

......

turret.x = tank.body.x;
turret.y = tank.body.y;
```